# Trying to associate years to university students

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have the following view which shows the student name, credits that the student has, and I just added a column called year all set to 0's.

```
+------------------+---------+------+
| StudentName      | Credits | Year |
+------------------+---------+------+
| Jon Macleod      |       0 |    0 |
| Carrie Gregory   |       0 |    0 |
| Matt Hayden      |       0 |    0 |
| Emily Scarlett   |      10 |    0 |
| Hailey Taylor    |      10 |    0 |
| Tj Davidson      |      10 |    0 |
| Alex Harry       |      20 |    0 |
| Matt Tosh        |      20 |    0 |
| Mitchell Gallant |      20 |    0 |
| Jon Harris       |      30 |    0 |
| Casey Macky      |      30 |    0 |
| James Doolittle  |      30 |    0 |
+------------------+---------+------+
```

I want to make it so that when a student has 0 credits they are a first year. when a student has 10 credits they are a 2nd year and so on..

I have the following script but cannot figure out why it does not work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Year AS
SELECT S.stu_name AS StudentName, SUM(Credits) AS Credits, 0 AS Year
        FROM Student AS S JOIN Enrollment AS E
        ON S.stu_id = E.stu_id
        Case 
            when (Year = '0' and Credits = 0 then 'FirstYear'
            when (Year = '0' and Credits = 10 then 'SecondYear' 
            else Year
         end as Year
        GROUP BY S.stu_id
        ORDER BY Credits;
```

Comment: What happens if two students have the same name?

Comment: Start with SELECT studentname, case when etc from...

Comment: I also have student ID's associated with the students. For this example I have just shown the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

As I miss the fact that MySql doesnt allow subqueries here is a proper solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Year AS
   SELECT S.stu_name AS StudentName, SUM(Credits) AS Credits, 
          Case When SUM(Credits)=0 then 'First Year'
               When SUM(Credits)=10 then 'Second Year'
               When SUM(Credits)=20 then 'Third Year'
               When SUM(Credits)=30 then 'Fourth Year'
               When SUM(Credits)=40 then 'Fifth Year'
               else '' end as year
     FROM Student AS S INNER JOIN Enrollment AS E
       ON S.stu_id = E.stu_id
     GROUP BY S.stu_id
    order by E.credits;
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/776c3/1

Comment: Thanks. However I receive the error that the views select contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Ooh I miss that fact from mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT S.stu_name AS StudentName, SUM(Credits) AS Credits,
    Case Credits
        when 0 then 'FirstYear'
        when 10 then 'SecondYear' 
        else Year
     end 'year'
              FROM student AS S
    GROUP BY S.stu_id
    ORDER BY Credits;
```